# Creating #444444 backgrounded image with ImageMagick unexpected results

Tags: imagemagick

When doing:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:#444444 whatever.png
```

Under:

```
Ubuntu 12.04
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2013-09-10 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

I find that the background of the image is white.  WHy is that? And how can I avoid that to happen if I want PNG format?

Thanks

Comment: Works for me with `ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2011-12-10 Q16`.

Comment: Oush. Let's see if somebody with 6.7.7-10 can give feedback. Thanks nwellnhof

Comment: Works with `ImageMagick 6.8.6-6 2013-08-04 Q16`.